# error with using urlopen in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

this code is showing me an error in any editor i use on my pc or browser, anyone can give me an idea of the problem where can it be, atom gives me this error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

```
import urllib


def reader():
    data= "I will take a shot at it"
    checker(data)

def checker(txt):
    recieved= urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+ txt)
    data= recieved.read()
    if (data== "true"): print "this text is cursed"
    elif (data== "false"): print "this text is fine"

reader()
raw_input()
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\templates\py\check_profanity.py", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\templates\py\check_profanity.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\base64.py", line 98, in <module>
    _urlsafe_encode_translation = string.maketrans(b'+/', b'-_')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Comment: Do you have a file called `string.py` lying around?